# Generic tracing mock class

Tags: mocking, moops

I am trying to construct a convenient mocking class using moops:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl '2014';
use Moops;
use Test::More;

class aClass {
  method m {}
  method l {}
};

class NotWorkingMockAClass
extends aClass {

  has methodCallLog => (
    is  => 'rw',
    default => sub { [] },
    isa     => ArrayRef
  );

  around m, l {
    push $self->methodCallLog, (caller(0))[3] =~ m/::(\w+)$/;
    $next->($self, @_ );
  }

};

my $mac = NotWorkingMockAClass->new();
$mac->m();
$mac->l();
$mac->m();

is( ($mac->methodCallLog)->[0], 'm', 'mcl[0] == m' );
is( ($mac->methodCallLog)->[1], 'l', 'mcl[1] == l' );
is( ($mac->methodCallLog)->[2], 'm', 'mcl[2] == m' );
```

This yields:

```
$ perl mocking.pl 
ok 1 - mcl[0] == m
not ok 2 - mcl[1] == l
#   Failed test 'mcl[1] == l'
#   at mocking.pl line 33.
#          got: 'm'
#     expected: 'l'
ok 3 - mcl[2] == m
```

So, the problem seems to be, that `caller()` always returns `m`, when I use the `around m,l ..` shortcut.

Defining the class like so:

```
class WorkingMockAClass
extends aClass {

  has methodCallLog => (
    is  => 'rw',
    default => sub { [] },
    isa     => ArrayRef
  );

  method _logAndDispatch( CodeRef $next, ArrayRef $args ){
    push $self->methodCallLog, (caller(1))[3] =~ m/::(\w)$/;
    $next->($self, @$args );
  }
  around m {
    $self->_logAndDispatch( $next, \@_ );
  }

  around l {
    $self->_logAndDispatch( $next, \@_ );
  }
};
```

works, but is a bit more verbose and cumbersome to write.

Is there a better option to achieve something like this with Moops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally Moops or otherwise, I wouldn't trust `caller` in any method that is potentially going to have modifiers applied to it. Nor would I trust it in those modifiers. You're relying too much on the internals of how method modifiers work. (Which will differ between Moo/Moose/Mouse.)

Have you tried something like this?

```
push @{ $self->methodCallLog }, Sub::Identify::sub_name($next);
```

(Or use Sub::Util instead of Sub::Identify.)

Comment: `Sub::Identify` works like a charm. Thinking further in the direction of genericity: Do you see a way of expressing something like `around * { }`? Which could then be placed in a role, enabling something like `aTracingClass extends aClass with Tracing`?

Comment: Not a Moops solution, but you could try MooseX::RoleQR. It allows `around qr/regexp/ => sub { ... }` to work in roles. (Moose already allows that to work in classes, just not in roles.)